# laravel retrieving profile firstname from model returns Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

Hi I am passing a `user_id` into a my user model and joining this to the profile table to retrieve the first name of the user as so:

```
public function scopefirstnameByUserId($id)
{

    return static::where('users.id','=',$id)->join('profiles', function ($join,$id) {
                    $join->where('profiles.user_id', '=', $id);
                    })->pluck('firstname');
}
```

usage:

`User::firstnameByUserId(2);`

However I get the following error:

`Missing argument 2 for User::{closure}()`

## Edit#

The function has now been updated to:

```
public function scopefirstnameByUserId($id)
{
    return static::where('users.id','=',$id)->join('profiles',function ($join) use ($id) {
                            $join->where('profiles.user_id', '=', $id);
                        })->pluck('firstname');
}
```

but now throws this error:

`Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
function ($join,$id) {

}
```

Should be:

```
function ($join) use ($id) {
    $join->where('profiles.user_id', '=', $id);
}
```

Comment: now I get this error `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string`

Comment: is if I `return $id ` i get this error: `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string`

Comment: Check the updated answer, you should not return anything from the closure.

Comment: thats what I have... `return static::where('users.id','=',$id)->join('profiles',function ($join) use ($id) { $join->where('profiles.user_id', '=', $id);})->pluck('firstname');` it still throws this error. check my updated question for formatted code